# change the position of an overlay using custom data attributes

Tags: css

I have a problem with this assignment I know i have mixed up so many things and it does not work at all. Could you please help me?
This is the task

the overlay has to be opened 
at specified left and top positions. These positions should be specified 
in the link used to open the overlay, using the custom data attributes data-x and data-y
Show Overlay
If neither of the two data attributes or only one of them is provided, the 
default values from the CSS should be used for the missing values. Also, 
make sure that the values for data-x and data-y are not outside the window area.
You can access the inner width and inner height of the current browser window 
with window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight, respectively.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Output</title>
    <style>
/* The Overlay: */
.overlay {
  /* General properties: */
  /* - Hidden when the page is first displayed */
  display: none;
  /* - Displayed on top of the other page elements */
  z-index: 10000;
  /* - Fixed position */
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  /* Appearance: */
  background-color: #ffffcc;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 40px 5px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 5px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px 5px #000000;
}

/* The Close Button: */
.overlay-close {
  /* Button image: */
  background-image: url(picture.jpg);
  /* Location: */
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
  top: -15px;
  /* Mouse cursor: */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Size: */
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
}
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
 /*var width = window.innerWidth;
 alert(width);1366
 var heigth= window.innerHeight;
 alert(heigth);667*/
 /* Extend the overlay code from the Virtual Session so that the overlay can be opened 
 at specified left and top positions. These positions should be specified 
 in the link used to open the overlay, using the custom data attributes data-x and data-y:
 <a href="#" data-overlay-id="#overlay1" class="overlay-link" data-x="100" data-y="50">
 Show Overlay</a>
 If neither of the two data attributes or only one of them is provided, the 
 default values from the CSS should be used for the missing values. Also, 
 make sure that the values for data-x and data-y are not outside the window area.
 You can access the inner width and inner height of the current browser window 
 with window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight, respectively.*/
 
 
 $(document).ready(function() {
 
 
 $('a.overlay-link').click(function() {

    var my_overlay_id = $($(this).attr('data-overlay-id'));
    my_overlay_id.prepend('<div class="overlay-close"></div>').show();
  var left = $($(this).attr('data-x'));// These act as kind of containers where elements can be stored and attributed a value later on (custom data attributes)
 $(this).css({left: left+"px"});
 var top = $($(this).attr('data-y'));
 $(this).css({top: top+"px"});
 if( $(this).css({left: left+"px"}) && $(this).css({top: top+"px"}) == 0 ||  $(this).css({left: left+"px"})== 0 || $(this).css({top: top+"px"})== 0 ){

 $(this).css({left: 50 +"px"});
 $(this).css({top: 50 +"px"});
 
 
 
 
 
 }
 

    $(document).on('click', '.overlay-close', function() {
      my_overlay_id.hide();
    });
  });

      });
    </script>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Output:</h3>
<div id="overlay1" class="overlay">
  <h2 data-overlay-title = 'Jesus I love you'>Hello, World!</h2>
  <p>I am an overlay.</p>
</div><a href="#" data-overlay-id="#overlay1" class="overlay-link" data-x="1000" data-y="1000" >Show Overlay</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you are mixing up some things, take a look at this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('a.overlay-link').on('click', function() {
    var my_overlay_id = $( $(this).attr('data-overlay-id') ) ,
        left = $(this).attr('data-x') ,
        top = $(this).attr('data-y') , 
        winW = $(window).width() ,
        winH = $(window).height();

    if( left > winW ) { left = 100; }
    if( top > winH ) { top = 100; }

    my_overlay_id.prepend('<div class="overlay-close"></div>').show();
    my_overlay_id.css({left: left+'px', top: top+'px'}).show();
  });


  $(document).on('click', '.overlay-close', function() {
    $('.overlay').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
/* The Overlay: */
.overlay {
  /* General properties: */
  /* - Hidden when the page is first displayed */
  display: none;
  /* - Displayed on top of the other page elements */
  z-index: 10000;
  /* - Fixed position */
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  /* Appearance: */
  background-color: #ffffcc;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 40px 5px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 5px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px 5px #000000;
}

/* The Close Button: */
.overlay-close {
  /* Button image: */
  background-image: url(picture.jpg);
  /* Location: */
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
  top: -15px;
  /* Mouse cursor: */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Size: */
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Output:</h3>
<div id="overlay1" class="overlay">
  <h2 data-overlay-title = 'Jesus I love you'>Hello, World!</h2>
  <p>I am an overlay.</p>
</div><a href="#" data-overlay-id="#overlay1" class="overlay-link" data-x="1000" data-y="1000" >Show Overlay</a>

<br />
<div id="overlay1" class="overlay">
  <h2 data-overlay-title = 'Jesus I love you'>Hello, World!</h2>
  <p>I am an overlay.</p>
</div><a href="#" data-overlay-id="#overlay1" class="overlay-link" data-x="250" data-y="0" >Show Overlay</a>
```